# Android Emulator - Google Play tab not appearing

Tags: android, android-emulator, google-play-services

I need to update Google Play Services in order to run my application on the emulator. Downgrading in the google services is not an option as I am using the fusedlocationproviderapi from 'com.google.android.gms:play-services location:11.0.0.

I have seen others with a Google Play tab on their emulator which allows them to update, but that tab does not show on my emulator. I don't get why. I have chosen the following:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: have you tried update your emulator in sdk manager?

Comment: There is no update available.

Answer (score 1):

Match your SDK version and update packages as shown in the screenshot

[image: Screen shot]

Comment: Please edit you other answer instead of posting this as a separate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Match your **SDK Tools** and **SDK Update** sites by attached snapshots: 
[image]

[image]

Comment: It looks exactly the same as mine.

Comment: ok, then please check your Google API by expanding the directory of your SDK version whether it is installed or not. And after then create a new AVD with Google API as the platform target. then navigate to setting > apps in your emulator and then find Google Play Services.